# Shared Elements Transition Animation with Fresco

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, fresco

I want to perform the shared elements transition animation after the image is loaded by fresco in my android app. I listen to the download events as described here; http://frescolib.org/docs/listening-download-events.html#_ In the onFinalImageSet event I run startPostponedEnterTransition as described here http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/03/activity-postponed-shared-element-transitions-part3b.html

The image is not shown. When I put a debug log to the onFinalImageSet event, I see that it's calling repeatedly. (11 times) When I comment out the startPostponedEnterTransition it's only called once, and works as expected. Somehow transition animation triggers fresco to load the image over and over. What is the issue and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the Fresco transition sample app](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/tree/master/samples/transition).
This shows you how to use transitions with Fresco.

If you want to know how this works under the hood (e.g. if you have a custom transition), take a look at [`DraweeTransition`](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/ffdb8842f63c93eeff703af038f82cbe84633f01/drawee/src/main/java/com/facebook/drawee/view/DraweeTransition.java).

Comment: Hi! I couldn't find the transition sample in the Fresco repo... has it changed places? Thanks and best regards!